# Reorder TOC output in nav.xhtml (epub) using map2epubHtmlTocImpl.xsl

Tags: xslt, nav, epub, dita, dita-ot

I'm trying to reorder the output of the topics in the nav.xhtml (epub) based on the following condition:
if topic A (could be more than 1 topic A) precedes topic B in the ditamap, then place the `<li>` of topic A after the `<li>` of topic B so that the nav would now look like this

```
<li>topic xx</li>
<li>topic xx</li>
<li>topic xx</li>...
<li>topic B</li>
<li>topic A</li>
<li>topic A</li>
```

I have managed to suppress the first output (i.e., natural order) of `<li>topic A</li>`. Then, I output the `<li>topic B</li>`.
I create the `<li>topic A</li>` (using xsl:for-each topicA) right after the `<li>topic B</li>`. I'm doing a manual build, but it's not quite working. I've used `preceding-sibling::*[@outputclass='topic A']/@id` to reinsert the id (or $linkId) value from topic A, but it's not working.
I did manage to insert the topic title for the preceding topic A by using:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*[@outputclass='topic A']" mode="nav-point-title"/>
```

but this only outputs the first title in the second li, so that it looks something like this:

```
    <li class="tocrm" id=""><a href="XX"></a></li>
    <li class="tocrm" id=""><a href="XX">Topic A1</a></li>
```

[NOTE that I haven't yet added the code to include the href yet. That's next on the list!]

It would be great if I could reuse the $linkId, etc. variables, but they don't seem to want to work in the context of topic B.
I know I'm probably not going to get an answer to this question as it's so complicated, but I've tried hundreds of iterations and I'm at a loss.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Sincerely,
struggling d4p user

Comment: Is `topic B` meant as an example topic, like `topic A` or are you looking for a particular topic named `topic B` and want to sort any preceding topics after that particular topic?

Comment: Just meant as an example. Our company uses a custom set of topics for publishing. E.g, topic A outputclass is announcement_page.

Comment: But the whole process of reordering, why doesn't that put the `topic XX` also after `topic B`? I am not quite sure what the reordering criteria are in general.

Comment: The rest of the topics will be output in their regular document order, so no reorganizing of the other topics. The condition is: if topic A precedes topic B, the in the nav,xhtml, topic A has to follow topic B.

Comment: Hi Martin: Your specific code did not work, but it gave me some insight on how to move ahead. I'll try a few more things to see if I can rebuild the NAV.xhtml file. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can just change the order of processing in e.g. https://github.com/dita4publishers/org.dita4publishers.epub/blob/develop/xsl/map2epubHtmlTocImpl.xsl#L40 by using

```
<xsl:variable name="b-topics" select="*[df:class(., 'map/topicref')][@title = 'topic B']"/>
<xsl:variable name="a-topics" select="$b-topics/preceding-sibling::*[df:class(., 'map/topicref')][@title = 'topic A']"/>
<xsl:variable name="others" select="$b-topics/preceding-sibling::*[df:class(., 'map/topicref')][@title != 'topic A']"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$others, $b-topics, $a-topics, $b-topics/following-sibling::*[df:class(., 'map/topicref')]" mode="#current">
```

instead of

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[df:class(., 'map/topicref')]" mode="#current">
```

Comment: It looks promising. I will give it a try and let you know the outcome! Thanks a lot.